# Unknown SOAP client option in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, soap, soap-api-v2

I am working to call Aramex Api for shipping rate in magento2.  I got php examples for Aramex, same as I follow below code to gert Shipping rate, But its throw `Unknown SOAP client option`

**My Code:**

```
  $params = array(
          "ClientInfo"              => array(
          "AccountCountryCode"  => "xxxxx",
          "AccountEntity"           => "xxx",
          "AccountNumber"           => "xxxxxxx",
          "AccountPin"          => "xxxxxxxxx",
          "UserName"            => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Password"            => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Version"         => "v1.0"
        ),

        "Transaction"           => array(
          "Reference1"          => "80742"
        ),

      "OriginAddress"       => array(
          "City"                    => "xxxxxxx",
          "StateOrProvinceCode"         => "xxxx",
          "PostCode"                    => "xxxxx",
          "CountryCode"             => "xxxxxxxxxx"
        ),

          "DestinationAddress"  => array(
          "City"                    => "xxxxx",
          "StateOrProvinceCode"         => "xxxxx",
          "PostCode"                    => "xxxxxx",
          "CountryCode"                 => "xxxxxxxxxx"
        ),
        "ShipmentDetails"       => array(
        "PaymentType"            => "xxxxx",
        "ProductGroup"           => "xxxxx",
        "ProductType"            => "xxxxxxx",
        "ActualWeight"           => array("Value" => 2.25, "Unit" => "KG"),
        "ChargeableWeight"           => array("Value" => 2.25, "Unit" => "KG"),
        "NumberOfPieces"         => 1
      )
    );

    $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client('/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/wsdl/aramex_rmkvwsdl.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
    $results = $soapClient->CalculateRate($params);
```

Suggest Me, How to call custom api using zend soap client and get api response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved this issue using global `SoapClient` not using `Zend Soap Client`

```
     $params = array(
          "ClientInfo"              => array(
          "AccountCountryCode"  => "xxxxx",
          "AccountEntity"           => "xxx",
          "AccountNumber"           => "xxxxxxx",
          "AccountPin"          => "xxxxxxxxx",
          "UserName"            => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Password"            => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Version"         => "v1.0"
        ),

        "Transaction"           => array(
          "Reference1"          => "80742"
        ),

      "OriginAddress"       => array(
          "City"                    => "xxxxxxx",
          "StateOrProvinceCode"         => "xxxx",
          "PostCode"                    => "xxxxx",
          "CountryCode"             => "xxxxxxxxxx"
        ),

          "DestinationAddress"  => array(
          "City"                    => "xxxxx",
          "StateOrProvinceCode"         => "xxxxx",
          "PostCode"                    => "xxxxxx",
          "CountryCode"                 => "xxxxxxxxxx"
        ),
        "ShipmentDetails"       => array(
        "PaymentType"            => "xxxxx",
        "ProductGroup"           => "xxxxx",
        "ProductType"            => "xxxxxxx",
        "ActualWeight"           => array("Value" => 2.25, "Unit" => "KG"),
        "ChargeableWeight"           => array("Value" => 2.25, "Unit" => "KG"),
        "NumberOfPieces"         => 1
      )
    );

    $soapClient = new \SoapClient('/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/wsdl/aramex_rmkvwsdl.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
    $results = $soapClient->CalculateRate($params);
```

Still I dont know, How to call Custom Api(shipping or Payment) in Magento 2.